# Jpa/Hibernate: avoid join on all join-table in an Entity that is UNIQUE per each relationship

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Easy example.

Table Resource.
Table Line_A.
Table Line_B.

Join-Table Resource_Line_A
Join-Table Resource_Line_B

Resource for Line_A could not be attached to Line_B and vice versa.

If I want all resource attached to Line_A for year 2021, in native sql I can write

```
Select * from Resource r join Resource_Line_A rla on r.id = rla.resource_id join Line_A la on rla.line_a_id = la.id where la.year = 2021
```

In Java, with repository, I've **lineARepository.findByYear(2021)**, but Hibernate show me this query

```
Select * from Resource r join Resource_Line_A rla on r.id = rla.resource_id join Line_A la on rla.line_a_id = la.id join Resource_Line_B rlb on r.id = rlb.resource_id join Line_B lb on rlb.line_b = lb.id where la.year = 2021
```

How I can avoid the useless join on Line_B table? All relationship are fetchtype.Lazy

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using a `@OneToOne(mappedBy = "..", fetch = LAZY)` for `lineB`? If so, you have to know that Hibernate 5.3 has a bug that was fixed in 5.4 which caused such associations to be eagerly fetched.

Comment: I tried with OneToOne on Line_a and Line_b but all association queries still triggered. I've hibernate 5.3.10. Do you have a link for this bug?

Comment: Sorry, but I would have to search through JIRA as well. Seems you will have to update to 5.4 then to get this performance optimization.